# How to turn this SQL query into an ActiveRecord query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a Model: `Score player:string, sport:string score:integer`.

I'm currently using find_by_sql for this SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY score ASC) AS a1 GROUP BY a1.player HAVING a1.sport = 'Soccer';`

Is it possible to translate the above SQL query into a Rails ActiveRecord query for portability sake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Score.group('player').having('sport = ?', 'Soccer').order('score')
```

will generate the SQL

```
SELECT 'scores'.* FROM 'scores' GROUP BY player HAVING sport = 'Soccer' ORDER BY score
```